# Issue With Dynamic menu directive in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a dynamic menu using angular JS. My directive is like

```
restrict : 'EA',
replace : true,
scope :{menu : "=menu"},
compile: function(element, attributes) {
    var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes){
              element.empty();
              element.append('<div id="cssmenu"><ul><div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
              for (i = 0;i<$scope.menu.length;i++){
              element.append("<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>  <span>"+$scope.menu[i].name+"</span></a></li>");
                    }
              element.append('</ul></div>');
                }
          return linkFunction;
     }
```

My HTML code is like

```
<div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MenuController">
  <my-menu menu="menu"></my-menu>
</div>
```

I am expecting an the resource to be generated like

```
  <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
    <div id="menu-button">Menu</div>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

But the current one generated is like

```
<my-menu menu="menu" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>
</ul>
</div>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</my-menu>
```

Issues I am facing

1) Why is the my-menu tag getting displayed ?

2) Why is the  and  tags getting closed before the tags are printed?

Also Please find the link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YH2vxLAN05UXeNa49TJF?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure on the behavior you're seeing, however I wonder why you're using the compile function vs just using a template?  I don't see anything a simple template can't handle here...

Comment: Actually what I need a function which will create template dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending things incorrectly to your element.  You append elements to elements with jQuery, and jQuery lite, which is what is included with angularjs.  You were using it like a string builder.  Here is the modifications which work as desired (code modified from your plnkr):

```
var linkFunction = function($scope, e, attributes){
                var element = angular.element('<ul />');;
                for (i = 0;i<$scope.menu.length;i++){
                    var li = angular.element('<li><a href="#">'+$scope.menu[i].name+'</a></li>');

                    if($scope.menu[i].subList.length > 0 ){
                        var subList = angular.element('<ul />')

                        for(j=0;j<$scope.menu[i].subList.length;j++){
                             var subLi = angular.element('<li><a href="#">'+$scope.menu[i].subList[j].name+'</a></li>');
                             subList.append(subLi);
                        }
                        li.append(subList);
                    }
                    element.append(li);
                }
                e.replaceWith(element);
        }
```

This produces the following markup:

```
<div ng-app="MenuDirective" ng-controller="MenuController" class="ng-scope">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Which is valid html markup. (your desired output is not due to the `div` as a child of the `ul`)
and renders like so:

- Home

  - Home1
  - Home2
- Contact

  - Contact1
  - Contact2

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7vLT7AvLVpJpoTxfnZgK?p=preview)

So as answers to your 2 questions:

1) Why is the my-menu tag getting displayed ?

> [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) removes the CONTENTS of your element, it doesn't make your
>   element into nothing.  Also, your element isn't replaced because there is no template supplied either by `template` property or by `templateUrl` property and thus there is nothing to replace your tag with.

2) Why is the and tags getting closed before the tags are printed?

> Your tags are getting inserted in the wrong places because you're
>   adding strange html nodes to the `end` of your root html node, not directly into the previous element you appended

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to add a `<div>` element as child from the `<ul>`.

Remove the `<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>`

Comment: it doesn't change anything